# Config ubuntu with static ip behind router

Tags: networking, server, 14.04

hello i have ubuntu server 14.04, and i want to create a public server, my provider gives me a ip, gateway and network mask, but my server stay under router, and i don't know how to config it. if i use dhcp i have ip like 1.1.1.62, my provider gives me 1.1.1.59. Is it possible to do it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Configure your router's public facing port with the IP given by your ISP. Then set up port forwarding on the router for the services you wish to make available to the public.